# Invoke multiple functions on wpf button click

Tags: wpf, powershell

Is it possible to call multiple functions on a button click?

For example I got this:

```
function environmentTemp(){
if($checkbox_1.Checked){


}
if($checkbox_2.Checked){}


}
if($checkbox_3.Checked){



}
```

and this:

```
function create(){
$UserList = Import-Csv -Path $txt_csv.Text -Delimiter ";"

<# ------- CREATE USERS ------- #>
foreach ($User in $UserList) {

    $OU = $User.path
    $UPN = $User.UPN
    $Password = $User.password 
    $Detailedname = $User.firstname + " " + $User.Lastname 
    $UserFirstname = $User.Firstname 
    $FirstLetterFirstname = $UserFirstname.substring(0,1) 
    $SAM =  $User.UPN
    $Company = $User.company
    $Description = $User.description
    $AccountExpirationDate = $User.accountexpirationdate

    $params = @{ 'Name'=$Detailedname;
                 'SamAccountName'=$SAM;
                 'UserPrincipalName'=$UPN+'@test.nl';
                 'DisplayName'=$Detailedname;
                 'GivenName'=$UserFirstname;
                 'Surname'=$User.Lastname;
                 'AccountPassword'=(ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force);
                 'Enabled'=$True;
                 'PasswordNeverExpires'=$True;
                 'Path'=$OU;
                 'Company'=$Company;
                 'Description'=$Description;
                 'AccountExpirationDate'=$AccountExpirationDate                 
                }

    New-ADUser @params
}
}
```

And this is my Wpf button object:

```
$button_add.Add_Click({create})
```

The user can choose for a enviroment. When I hit the create button I want to execute the function environmentTemp and Create at the same time or is it possible to store the choices of the check boxes into a variable?

Comment: try: `$button_add.Add_Click({create; environmentTemp})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just *seperate the statements* using a **semicolon**:

```
$button_add.Add_Click({create; environmentTemp})
```